# Mathematica 9 cannot solve this Integral. Mathematica 8 could. Is this a bug?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, version-9, backslide

I was trying to (re)calculate a problem of an older [Wolfram blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2009/10/28/mathematica-and-the-american-mathematical-monthlys-problems-and-solutions-section/) (Problem 11457, by M. L. Glasser) with Mathematica 9.0.0.0 (on OS X 10.8.2).

```
Assuming[0 < a < b, Integrate[ArcCos[x/Sqrt[(a + b) x - a b]], {x, a, b}]]
```

Instead of the expected solution, it just returns the integral unevaluated. Is this a regression?

**More details:**
As pointed out in the commentes, the indefinite integral

```
Integrate[ArcCos[x/Sqrt[(a + b) x - a b]], x]
```

still gives the same result in Mathematica 8 and 9.

The next two each returned [ConditionalExpression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) in Mathematica 8 but return unevaluated in Mathematica 9:

```
Integrate[ArcCos[x/Sqrt[(a + b) x - a b]], {x, a, b}]
Integrate[ArcCos[x/Sqrt[(a + b) x - a b]], {x, a, b}, Assumptions -> 0 <= a <= b]
```

The actual problem

```
Integrate[ArcCos[x/Sqrt[(a + b) x - a b]], {x, a, b}, Assumptions -> 0 < a < b]
```

computes correctly to `((a - b)^2 \[Pi])/(4 (a + b))` in Mathematica 8 but still returns unevaulated in Mathematica 9.

Comment: I can confirm that it does not work in MMA 9 win 7 64 bit, but works in MMA 8.0.1. In MMA8 I get `((a - b)^2 \[Pi])/(4 (a + b))`

Comment: The topic is misleading. I thought it was about Regression in Statistics

Comment: It works as expected in Mma 8.0.0 too

Comment: You can also send to this support@wolfram.com and report it as an issue with 9.

Comment: Mathematica 8 and 9 give the same correct indefinite integral. The difference is in the calculation for the limits of integration.

Comment: So solving the indefinite integral must use a different branch cut. All the limits looks like they're being calculated correctly, but ultimately ends up giving a different result. The limits and indefinite integral are correct and identical in 8 and 9. So this looks like a regression with integrate itself.

Comment: As suggested, I emailed support@wolfram.com about this.

Comment: Here are another instances of definite integrals which are unevaluated in `ver.9` while they are in `ver.8` http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18327/definite-integral-takes-a-very-long-time/18328#18328

Comment: @Artes I may have missed something at your link. I did not see a regression example therein. If you post an explicit Integrate[...] I'll take a look.

Comment: [I am NOT putting this into a response.] Yes, this appears to be a regression. Investigating...

Comment: just to experiment, what if you split the `Assumptions` into `0 < a && 0 < b && a < b`

Comment: Separating the conditions does not help. Setting GenerateConditions -> False does however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works in V9.0.1:

```
Assuming[0 < a < b, 
  Integrate[ArcCos[x/Sqrt[(a + b) x - a b]], {x, a, b}, 
   GenerateConditions -> False]] // Timing
(* {3.835651, ((a - b)^2 π)/(4 (a + b))} *)
```

Comment: Good catch! Works with v9.0.0.0 also.