# Solving equations involving integrals

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I need to find the value of $z$ for a particular value of $D_c$ (eg. $500$), but $z$ is inside an integral, and I'm not able to use `Solve` since the integral is giving `Hypergeometric2F1` function as the output.

```
OmegaM = 0.3111;
OmegaLambda = 0.6889;
Dc = 500;

eqn = Integrate[(OmegaM (1 + z1)^3 + OmegaLambda)^(-1/2), {z1, 0, z},
                  Assumptions -> z > 0]
```

> ```
> -1.1473+(1.20482+1.20482z)Hypergeometric2F1[0.333333,0.5,1.33333,-0.451589(1.+z)^3]
> ```

```
zvalue = Solve[eqn == Dc, z]
```

> ```
> Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the 
> system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present
> in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact
> input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help.
> ```

Is there any other way I can solve this equation?

Also, Integrate is taking some time and I'd like it to be fast since I need to put it in a loop with lots of $z$ values to be computed for corresponding $D_c$ values.

Comment: There is a factor of c/H0 multiplied with the integral where c=300000, H0=68. I think that will make the equation consistent. Thanks https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/35368/superciocia for suggesting FindRoot, it solves the issue. Now I just want to know if I can speed up this integral somehow.

Comment: Strictly the same integral is here [Definite integral takes a very long time](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18327/definite-integral-takes-a-very-long-time?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your integral I get the following equation (same as yours when you plot it):

```
eqn[z_] := 
 3.2566440560469836` - (
  3.5857498598223954` Hypergeometric2F1[1/6, 1/2, 7/
    6, -(2.2144005143040824`/(1 + z)^3)])/Sqrt[1 + z]
```

Both `Solve`and `NSolve` fail.

So I tried `FindRoot`:

```
Dc = 3.1;
FindRoot[ eqn[z] - Dc, {z, 0}]
```

> ```
> {z -> 523.001}
> ```

which agrees with a graphical solution:
[image]

I don't think it has a solution for `Dc=500` as the `eqn` flattens out to `3.25664` as $z\rightarrow \infty$:

```
Limit[ eqn[z], {z -> ∞}]
```

> ```
> 3.25664
> ```

Comment: How's your `eqn` is so different than OP's?

Comment: It's the same function. I had to change the integrand from $z1+1$ to $z2$ in order for Mathematica to give me an analytical result. Maybe it's because of different versions.

Comment: Strange, I can reproduce this only for `z1+1` as new variable, and `Assumptions -> z>0`. Otherwise it's OP's function.

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: 12.1. Yours? And did you specify `Assumptions` for `eqn[z_]`?

Comment: I have 11.3 . I specified `Assumptions->z>0`yes

Answer (score 7):

We will demonstrate that the exact formula for $z$ reads:
$$z=\wp\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{\Omega_M}}{2}D_c+\wp^{-1}\big(1;0,-\frac{4\Omega_\Lambda}{\Omega_M}\big);0,-\frac{4\Omega_\Lambda}{\Omega_M}\bigg)-1$$
where $\wp(x;g_2,g_3)$ is the Weierstrass elliptic function, which yields a value $w$ in the elliptic integral $$x=\int^{w}_{\infty}\frac{d t}{\sqrt{4t^3-g_2\;t-g_3}}$$ and so  **generalizing the answer** to the original question for **any integrand** of the form $\frac{1}{\sqrt{R(t)}}$, where $R(t)$ is a **fourth or a third order polynomial** in $t$.
This formula can be implemented in the following way:

```
z[ Dc_, OM_, OL_]:= WeierstrassP[ Sqrt[OM/4] Dc+ InverseWeierstrassP[ 1, { 0,-4OL/OM}],
                                  { 0, -4OL/OM}]-1
```

We rationalize numeric constants to play with the system seamlessly (although this step is not neccesary):

```
{ OM, OL} = Rationalize[{ OmegaM = 0.3111, OmegaLambda = 0.6889}];
```

Let's derive $z$: 
$$D_c=\int^{z}_{0}\frac{d s}{\sqrt{\Omega_M (s+1)^3+\Omega_{\Lambda}}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\Omega_M}}\int^{z+1}_{1}\frac{d s}{\sqrt{4 s^3+\frac{4\Omega_{\Lambda}}{\Omega_M}}}=\\=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\Omega_M}}\Bigg(\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{d s}{\sqrt{4 s^3+\frac{4\Omega_{\Lambda}}{\Omega_M}}}-\int^{\infty}_{z+1}\frac{d s}{\sqrt{4 s^3+\frac{4\Omega_{\Lambda}}{\Omega_M}}}\Bigg)=\\=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\Omega_M}}\Bigg(-\wp^{-1}\big(1;0,-\frac{4\Omega_\Lambda}{\Omega_M}\big)+\wp^{-1}\big(z+1;0,-\frac{4\Omega_\Lambda}{\Omega_M}\big)\Bigg)$$ and this implies our formula for $z$.

The formula for $z$ is valid in the range $0<D_c<D_{m}=3.25664$ and we can also derive an exact formula for $D_m$:
$$D_m=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\Omega_M}} \Re\Big( 2\;\omega_{1}(0,g_3)-\wp^{-1}\big(1;0,g_3\big)\Big)$$
where $\Re$ is the real part, $\omega_{1}(0,g_3)$ is the Weierstrass half period and $g_3$ is the Weierstrass invariant, in our case $g_3=-\frac{4\Omega_{\Lambda}}{\Omega_M}$, 
implementing it:

```
g3=-4OL/OM;
Dm = 2/Sqrt[OM]( 2WeierstrassHalfPeriodW1[{0, g3}]-InverseWeierstrassP[1,{0, g3}])//Re//N
```

> ```
> 3.25664
> ```

`Dm` been calculated in version `12.1`, however in earlier versions one should evaluate simply `Dm = -2/Sqrt[OM] InverseWeierstrassP[1,{0, g3}]`. This is because `InverseWeierstrassP[1,{0, g3}]` is computed in a adjacent parallelogram (see e.g [this discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63121/integrate-yields-complex-value-while-after-variable-transformation-the-result-i/160055#160055)). One should also note better handling of symbolic input in `WeierstrssHalfPeriodW1` etc.
For the presentation of the structure of $z$ being an elliptic function (shifted and rescaled $\wp$) we define:

```
wHP = Through @ { WeierstrassHalfPeriodW1,WeierstrassHalfPeriodW2,
                  WeierstrassHalfPeriodW3} @{ 0,-4OL/OM}//ReIm
                 // FullSimplify;
GraphicsRow @ Table[ ContourPlot[ Evaluate @ Table[p[z[x+I y,OM,OL]] ==k,       
                            {k, wHP[[#1,#2]]& @@@ {{2,1},{2,2},{3,1},{3,2}}}],
                        {x, -8, 8}, {y, -8, 8}, ContourStyle ->Thread[
                          {Thick,{Red,Darker@Cyan,Darker@Green,Orange}}]],
                     {p, {Re, Im}}]
```

[image]

There was an assumption that $z>0$, however $D_c=500$ can be reached for negative $z$, e.g.

```
z[ 500,OM, OL]//N//Chop
```

> ```
> -1.73134
> ```

and for $0< z<D_m$ e.g.

```
z[ 2, OM, OL]//N//Chop
```

> ```
> 7.13731
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
OmegaM = 0.3111 // Rationalize;
OmegaLambda = 0.6889 // Rationalize;
Dc = 500;

eqn = Integrate[(OmegaM (1 + z1)^3 + OmegaLambda)^(-1/2), {z1, 0, z}, 
  Assumptions -> z > 0]
```

[image]

For `z > 0`, `eqn` is monotonically increasing

```
Assuming[z > 0, D[eqn, z] > 0 // Simplify]

(* True *)
```

The maximum value of `eqn` is

```
(lim = Limit[eqn, z -> Infinity]) // N

(* 3.25664 *)

LogLinearPlot[{lim, eqn}, {z, 10^-2, 10^4},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.3, .7}]]
```

[image]

Consequently, `eqn` can never equal the specified value of `Dc`

Using instead

```
Dc = 2;
```

Use [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)

```
zvalue = NSolve[{eqn == Dc, z > 0}, z]

(* {{z -> 7.13731}} *)
```

Or [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
zvalue = FindRoot[eqn == Dc, {z, 1}]

{z -> 7.13731}
```

Or [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) (provides the exact value as a Root expression)

```
zvalue = Reduce[{eqn == Dc, z > 0}, z]
```

[image]

```
zvalue // N

(* z == 7.13731 *)
```

Similarly with [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

```
zvalue = Solve[{eqn == Dc, z > 0}, z][[1]]
```

[image]